# Вывод данных в консоль, с ее очисткой

Tags: java, консоль, обновление

Доброго дня, коллеги.
Есть один код, который выводит в консоль таблицу случайных булевых значений.
Все бы ничего, но мне нужно, чтобы значения не выводились потоком, одно за другим, а изменялись в реальном времени.
Те по аналогии с часами в консоли: время должно не писаться в новой строке с каждой новой секундой, а должно находиться, и обновляться в изначальной.

```
boolean[][] dots = new boolean[5][5];

    Random randomBoolean = new Random();

    //Now i want to create a table with random boolean values
    //Eternal loop
    for (;;) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                    dots[i][j] = randomBoolean.nextBoolean();
                    System.out.print(dots[i][j] + "\t");
                    }
                    //Close the column
                System.out.println();
            }
           System.out.println();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

    }
```

Что и куда мне нужно для этого добавить? 
Спасибо

Comment: Это джава.. Врял ди тут удастся что-то легко добавить для этого...

Comment: Никогда о таком не слышала. Вот что говорит английский stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console

Comment: Я пробовал юзать советы из английского стака, но ничего не заработало =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сама Java очищать консоль не умеет. Но есть небольшая библиотечка, позволяющая отправлять управляющие последовательности в любую ANSI-совместимую консоль - [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi):

```
import java.util.Random;
import org.fusesource.jansi.AnsiConsole;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();

        Random randomBoolean = new Random();

        for (;;) {
            System.out.print("\u001b[2J");
            System.out.flush(); 

            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        System.out.print(randomBoolean.nextBoolean() + "\t");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();

                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то работает и без библиотеки, может быть так и должно? :)

Comment: @AlexChermenin в Windows тоже?

Comment: И лучше использовать последовательность `\u001b[6F`, причём - после вывода (возвращаемся вверх на 6 строк и выводим снова). Подробнее про последовательности есть в вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI

Comment: пока что нет возможности проверить, как получится - отпишусь